# Is there a way to undelete deleted permissions in cloud IAM Admin on the google cloud platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have accidentally locked myself out of my own project. It is still running with cloud SQL instances and a Kubernetes cluster, but I cannot view anything about it or stop it.

I was removing permissions which I thought were just for bigquery, but it was for the whole project.

Now permissions are denied for everything, and I cannot even view the project name on the Google cloud platform dashboard.

Comment: Try contacting Google Support?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your project is now an Orphan Project.

I recommend to [contact GCP support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing/#contact_support) in order to verify the ownership of your project and get it back.

In future to avoid orphaned projects I recommend to follow this recommendation:

[How to avoid orphaned projects](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-suspension-guidelines#how_to_avoid_orphaned_projects)

> In order to prevent a project from becoming orphaned, we recommend that more than one owner be associated with the project at all times.

> If a project belongs to an [Organization resource](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy#organizations), then it will always have at least the Organization as an owner and as such will not be orphaned. The Organization administrator has full control over each project in the Organization. To eliminate the risk of a Project resource becoming orphaned, we recommend [obtaining an Organization resource](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization) and migrating all production projects under it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will contact billing support

Comment: if you find my answer useful, please consider upvoting/accepting it, thank you!